# Why there are two values for the genus of an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the intro of the Algebraic Geometry Andrea Gathmann's book and I'm not sure about how to answer the exercise 0.6 :

We argued that a polynomial of degree $d$ in two complex variables gives rise to a surface of genus $\frac{(d-1))d-2)}{2}$.  However the polinomio $x_2^2=(x_1-1)\dots(x_1-2n)$ gives us a surface of genus $n-1$. Can you see why these two results do not contradict each other?

One possible answer is that there two types of genus. Reading Wikipedia, now I know that the two genus are the arithmetic one and the geometric one. I think the degree formula gives one genus and the other construction in the book gives the other genus.

The other possible answer is that that you can't degenerate (whatever it means) the polinomio $x_2^2=(x_1-1)\dots(x_1-2n)$ to a polinomio which can be factorized as products of liner polinomios in two variables without perturb the genus.

Comment: Please include the statement of the exercise in your post: [questions on MSE should be self-contained](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/how-self-contained-should-questions-be). Another reason to do this is that not everyone who can answer the question will necessarily have the book in front of them, and you miss out on potential answers by not including this statement in your post.

Comment: The hyperelliptic curve is NOT a smooth plane curve, that is, it is not a smooth curve in $\mathbb P^2$ (except for elliptic curve, of course). If one compactify the affine curve $y^2=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_{2n})$, there is an singularity at infinity.